# Django. Кто как создает urlpatterns?

Tags: python, django

Меня интересует кто как создает urls для Django.

Больше интересует динамически, чем вручную каждый путь руками писать.
Например в ModelAdmin есть функция get_urls, которая для каждой модели создает свои пути.

**Делитесь своим опытом!**

```
def get_urls(self):
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

    def wrap(view):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)

    info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.module_name

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$',
            wrap(self.changelist_view),
            name='%s_%s_changelist' % info),
        url(r'^add/$',
            wrap(self.add_view),
            name='%s_%s_add' % info),
        url(r'^(.+)/history/$',
            wrap(self.history_view),
            name='%s_%s_history' % info),
        url(r'^(.+)/delete/$',
            wrap(self.delete_view),
            name='%s_%s_delete' % info),
        url(r'^(.+)/$',
            wrap(self.change_view),
            name='%s_%s_change' % info),
    )
    return urlpatterns
```

Comment: Не сталкивался ни разу с такой необходимостью. Регэкспов как-то хватало всегда.

Comment: Задача простая, например нам нужно создать 2 страницы, которые указаны в списке pages = ['tuda', 'cuda']. Что бы создать их вы же не будете в регекспе писать ^(?P<page>.*), какая функция их поймает? Так что придется написать функцию, которая генерит urlpatterns из 2 строк, например такую

    urls_list = ()
        for page in ['tuda', 'cuda']:
            urls_list.append(url(r'^%s/$' % page, 'path.to.views.pages', name='%s' % page))

и после просто прибавим к urlpatterns + url_list и у нас добавится еще 2 ссылки.
Делается это для того, если у вас на двух страницах одно и то же содержание.

Comment: Если обе страницы обрабатываются одной вьюхой (что наиболее вероятно), создаем правило вида `'^\w+/$'`, а уж вьюха сама пусть решает, что является валидной страницей и возвращает 404, когда надо:

    if page not in page_list: return 404

Нафига логику в url-паттерны сувать? По мне, так лучше держать их как можно более явными

Comment: Ну может быть да. Просто мной движет познание и заинтересованность в самом процессе)) По этому и выходит такие бредовые мысли и их реализация. Ну вдруг все таки, кто-то создает генерируя урлы. Мне интересна сама технология.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Посмотрел код. Здесь, на мой взгляд, несколько другой случай, нежели "нежелание писать руками". Так как джанговская админка - динамически подстраивается под зарегистрированные модели, ей **необходимо** регистрировать `urlы` таким способом.

```
url(r'^$',
    wrap(self.changelist_view),
    name='%s_%s_changelist' % info),
```

В этом коде то, в принципе, и нет *динамических* url - они все типовые. А их *динамичность* (то есть зависимость от имени используемой модели в данном случае) находится на один уровень выше (`/my_model/` и `/my_model/add/`). Здесь же регистрируются типовые действия для каждой модели: история действий, добавить, удалить и т. д.

Динамичность здесь выражается только в уникальном `name`, который используется в основном для `reverse` и создается главным образом, как я понимаю, для ускорения работы этой функции (чтобы не было необходимости в поисках нужной функции проверять ее на каждый регэксп - ну то есть для чего и был придуман этот атрибут: указал имя url - и вперед).

Если у вас приложение делает нечто подобное джанговской админке - да, такая динамичность имеет место быть. В ином случае логике не место в url-паттернах, как я и написал в комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: Вот в описании описал не очень подробно, что хотел, но в вопросе написал точно "Кто как создает urlpatterns?". Не конкретно что бы было динамически, а способы создания урлов.
Вот админка джанги создает по зарегистрированным моделям, я например сейчас пока только придумал как уже указал, другие как нибудь по другому, по этому интересно способы создания урлов.
Понятное дело, что надо создавать в urls.py всё, но мб кто нибудь тоже любит писать (не один же я такой) что-то свое :)
Ответ хороший, спасибо.

Comment: Ок, просто мне непонятны юзкейсы таких "экспериментов".
Извращения над URL - самое меньшее ведь, что можно сделать в Джангой. Но вопрос в целом интересный, плюсанул. :)